# Java Linked List How to create a node that holds a string and an int?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have been at this literally all day. I can create linked lists no problem and display/delete the data in them. My problem is though that I am not sure how to create a linked list of flights with each node including a reference to a linked list of passengers? This is an assignment in my advanced Algorithms class. I am drawing a blank here?

Comment: ***advanced*** algorithms class???

Comment: Are you using java.util.LinkedList or do you have to roll your own for the assignment?

Comment: I am trying to use the built in java.util.LinkedList It was not specified which to use. So I am figuring the Java built in would more than satisfy my needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an object that holds a Passenger:

```
public class Passenger
{
    private String name;
    private int id;
}
```

Then give Flight a List of Passengers:

```
public class Flight
{
    private List<Passenger> passengers;
}
```

Now you can have a List of Flights:

```
public class Schedule
{
    private List<Flight> flights;
}
```

You needs lots more code in each.  Be sure to override equals and hashCode for Passenger and Flight to make sure that they work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well, can't you just create a `Flight` class and a `Passenger` class?

```
class Flight {
   private LinkedList<Passenger> passengers;
   ...
}

class Passenger {
  ... 
}

LinkedList<Flight> flights = ...
```