# Creating a Java List of Generic types

Tags: java, list

I have created a Java class MyObject:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public final String s; 
    public final int i; 
    public final int j;
    ...
}
```

I want to create a List of this type, but I am getting a "Cannot instantiate the type List" error

```
private java.util.List<MyObject> myObjectss = new java.util.List<MyObject>();
```

I tried the solution in this question (4 vote answer) but I get a "The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments " error...

[Java Linked List How to create a node that holds a string and an int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246997/java-linked-list-how-to-create-a-node-that-holds-a-string-and-an-int)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an *interface* and therefore cannot be instantiated. You could try:

```
private java.util.List<MyObject> myObjectss = new java.util.ArrayList<MyObject>();
```

[`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is a class that implements the `List` interface.

---

**Edit** Just saw that you needed a [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html), try this:

```
private java.util.List<MyObject> myObjectss = new java.util.LinkedList<MyObject>();
```

Comment: OP needs `LinkedList`. It's pretty similar but still the answer could have better guidance.

Comment: ah, I see now. I thought I might have been using List wrong...but not how. Thanks!

Comment: Also, you *can* instantiate an interface in your code by creating an [*anonymous class*](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm), but it's clumsy to use it for the `List` interface.

Comment: Yes you can do this also. I don't remember if this would be called "instantiating `List`" since you are technically implementing it in an anonymous class and then instantiating that class. But anyway, that's a technicality.